# Get response from an ip address in python

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, response

Given an ip, how can i make an http request to this ip in python?
For example, if i want to get a file names 't1.txt' from the server that resides on '8.8.8.8', how can i do so?
I've tried using httplib and urllib2.
(It's better if the proper way will be by using standard Python libs).
Thanks a lot,
Iko.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? An IP address can be used in place of a URL.

Comment: Yeah, the solution can also be a script that sends an http request to the ip itself (even if we won't know the visible url)

Comment: This also depends on what service you are running on the server. webserver, rest, soap, simple fileshare,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://8.8.8.8/t1.txt", "t1.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple url retrieval, [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) is perfectly OK (and is a standard Python library)...

... but if you are looking for something more easy to use in more complex cases, you should take a look at [request](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://8.8.8.8/t1.txt')
```